# Golang. Help to optimize piece of the code

Tags: go

I have the code

```
if config.Process.TraceLog != "" {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(config.Process.TraceLog, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Trace.SetOutput(f)
}

if config.Process.InfoLog != "" {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(config.Process.InfoLog, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Info.SetOutput(f)
}
if config.Process.WarningLog != "" {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(config.Process.WarningLog, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    Warning.SetOutput(f)
}

if config.Process.ErrorLog != "" {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(config.Process.ErrorLog, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Error.SetOutput(f)
}
```

1. What is good way to shorten it? I don't want to repeat same very similar block 4 times.
2. How to make it in a loop? I tried to create a map with file name and logger object, but don't know how to post a reference correctly

Comment: What does your config.Process looks like?

Comment: This is just a struct containing all config options. Config file is a JSON and it was parsed to the variable config (it is not a package )

Answer (score 1):

This is how i finally did it

```
m := map[string]*log.Logger{
    config.Process.TraceLog:   Trace,
    config.Process.InfoLog:    Info,
    config.Process.WarningLog: Warning,
    config.Process.ErrorLog:   Error,
}
for filepath, l := range m {
    if filepath != "" {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        l.SetOutput(f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (you might need to adjust the types of the function in the interface or drop the interface completely):

```
setLogIfNotEmpty(config.Process.TraceLog, Trace)
setLogIfNotEmpty(config.Process.InfoLog, Info)
setLogIfNotEmpty(config.Process.WarningLog, Warning)
setLogIfNotEmpty(config.Process.ErrorLog, Error)

interface SetOutputer {
    SetOutput(*os.File)
}

func setLogIfNotEmpty(file string, log SetOutputer) {
    if file != "" {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(file, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error opening log file: %v", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        log.SetOutput(f)
    }
}
```